# Ajax Pagination for ajax loaded data in cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CAKEPHP 3.4. Ajax pagination is working fine for first loaded data. then I am using ajax filter to filter list which is working fine. When I am clicking page 2 on ajax loaded pagination it is loading all the previous data before filtering. This is the following code  which I have used for pagination.

```
$(".pagination a").bind("click", function (event) {
if(!$(this).attr('href'))
  return false;
$.ajax({
  dataType:"html", 
  evalScripts:true,
  data:'state=1&category=6',
  success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#searchResult").html(data);}, 
  url:$(this).attr('href')
});
return false;
```

});

Comment: Did you check out the examples [in the sandbox](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples) about AJAX pagination?

Comment: No. actually my pagination is working fine form 1st time loaded data but when I am loading the data from ajax it is not working properly.

Comment: Are you accounting for the changing DOM? Any JS that is not live binding will usually stop working otherwise.

Comment: yes I think so. is there any suitable way to do that in CakePHP  or through jquery? I need to do the filter with ajax and pagination.

Comment: Check my first link :) It shows a simple viable solution incl fallback (in case JS is broken or diabled).